# My web crawler is throwing errors instead of fetching data

Tags: python, web-crawler

I can't figure out any mistake I've done in my code. Xpaths have got no
issues. Functions are doing good if checked individually. When I run the 
spider it gets the following error. Basically, it occurs when it reaches
the Layer2 function to be processed. When I checked in the firstly produced
links I could notice that those were full-fledged urls. What should I do to
get results at this moment. Thanks in advance.

### Spider:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

def Startpoint():
    address = "https://www.sephora.ae/en/stores/"
    page = requests.get(address)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    titles=tree.xpath('//li[contains(@class,"level0")]')
    for title in titles:
        href = title.xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"level0")]/@href')[0]
        Layer2(href)

def Layer2(address):
    page = requests.get(address)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    titles=tree.xpath('//div[@class="product-manufacturer"]')
    for title in titles:
        href = title.xpath('.//a/@href')[0]
        Endpoint(href)

def Endpoint(address):
    page = requests.get(address)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    titles=tree.xpath('//div[@class="add-to-cart"]')
    for title in titles:
        Name = title.xpath('.//div[@class="h2"]/text()')[0]
        Price = title.xpath('.//span[@class="price"]/text()')[0]
        print('{}{}'.format(Name, Price))      

Startpoint()
```

Modified the above code according to Max Paymar's suggestion. Now it is working.

Comment: I've never used this library so I could be wrong but it looks like the `url` variable needs to be modified so that it's a string. The brackets `'['` in the error message definitely seem out of place.

Comment: Thanks Max Paymar for your answer. I've fixed the list issues but that doesn't solve the problem either. When i checked printing the first produced links, I didn't see any url missing "http://" but the console shows that very thing. Really confused.

Comment: Now it says the URL is `''` which is an empty string. So something is still going wrong when you are generating the URL.

Comment: `link=''.join(str(e) for e in href)` this line is the culprit. the list comprehension you are using is not generating any strings.

Comment: Hey  Max Paymar, please write your first comment in the answer so that I can accept it. I got it solved already following your first suggestion.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used this library so I could be wrong but it looks like the url variable needs to be modified so that it's a string. The brackets '[' in the error message definitely seem out of place.